# How to merge these two Jsons?

Tags: python, json, django

I have two models in Django which I'm getting Json outputs from:

*Models (Simplified)*

```
class ServiceSubCategory(models.Model):
    service_category = models.ForeignKey(ServiceCategory)
    name_fa = models.CharField(default='', max_length=200)
    name_en = models.CharField(default='', max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return  self.service_category.name_fa+' -> '+ self.name_fa

class Service(models.Model):
    service_sub_category = models.ForeignKey(ServiceSubCategory)
    img_fa = models.ImageField(default='img/default_service.png',upload_to='img/service/')
    caption_fa = models.CharField(default='',max_length=200)
    caption_en = models.CharField(default='',max_length=200)

    def as_json(self):
        return {
                'id': self.id,
                'caption_fa': self.caption_fa,
                'caption_en': self.caption_en,
                'img_fa': unicode(self.img_fa),
        }
```

I want to get the first model primary key values and merge it with the JSON I'm getting from the second model:

I'm getting this JSON from ServiceSubCategory:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

By running this code:

```
idJson=json.dumps(list(ServiceSubCategory.objects.values_list('id',flat=True)))
```

and getting this Json:

```
[{"caption_fa": "some value", "caption_en": "something", "id": 2, "img_fa": "img/default_service.png"},
{"caption_fa": "somthing", "caption_en": "somthing", "id": 1, "img_fa": "img/service/IMAG0099_1H3sdjX.jpg"}]
```

By this

```
cat = ServiceSubCategory.objects.get(id=1)
dictionary=[obj.as_json() for obj in Service.objects.filter(service_sub_category=cat)]
```

What I want is to merge those two JSons to get something like this:

```
[["1":{"caption_fa": "some value", "caption_en": "something", "id": 2, "img_fa": "img/default_service.png"},
{"caption_fa": "somthing", "caption_en": "somthing", "id": 1, "img_fa": "img/service/IMAG0099_1H3sdjX.jpg"}],
["2":{"caption_fa": "some value", "caption_en": "something", "id": 3, "img_fa": "img/default_service.png"},
{"caption_fa": "somthing", "caption_en": "somthing", "id": 4, "img_fa": "img/service/IMAG0099_1H3sdjX.jpg"}]]
```

This is how I'm trying to do this:

```
def service(request):
    idList=ServiceSubCategory.objects.values_list('id',flat=True)

    idJson=json.dumps(list(ServiceSubCategory.objects.values_list('id',flat=True)))
        for i in idList:
            dictionary=[obj.as_json() for obj in Service.objects.filter(service_sub_category=i)]
            idJson[i].append(dictionary) #Error
    return HttpResponse(idJson, content_type='application/json')
```

And I'm getting error at `idJson[i].append(dictionary)`:

> 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

I really have no idea how should I do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, instead of two JSONs, I converted the forst array to a string array (`["1","2","3",...]`) and using `zip` I've merged two arrays and then converted it to a JSON:

```
idArray='["1","2","3",...]'
dictionaries='[[{"caption_fa": "some value", "caption_en": "something", "id": 2},
{"caption_fa": "somthing", "caption_en": "somthing", "id": 1}],
[{"caption_fa": "some value", "caption_en": "something", "id": 3},
{"caption_fa": "somthing", "caption_en": "somthing", "id": 4}]]'
import json
theArray = dict(zip(idArray, dictionaries))
theJson =  json.dumps(theArray )
```

And the result is:

```
[["1":{"caption_fa": "some value", "caption_en": "something", "id": 2},
    {"caption_fa": "somthing", "caption_en": "somthing", "id": 1}],
    ["2":{"caption_fa": "some value", "caption_en": "something", "id": 3},
    {"caption_fa": "somthing", "caption_en": "somthing", "id": 4}]]
```

Comment: whatever result you have printed here, it is an illegal statement in python. simply copy paste it into a python shell of your choice and you shall see

Comment: @bmbigbang I've tested it and got my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a list of dictionaries and a list of keys and want to create a dictionary of dictionaries with keys from the second list.
Here is some simplified example of doing this (assuming both your lists are the same length):

```
ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]
dicts = [{'a':'b'}, {'c':'d'}, {'e':'f'}, {'g':'h'}]
dict_of_dicts = {i:d for i, d in zip(ids, dicts)}
print dict_of_dicts
#{1: {'a': 'b'}, 2: {'c': 'd'}, 3: {'e': 'f'}, 4: {'g': 'h'}}
```

Comment: It doesn't actually return what your answer suggests. I get blank spaces and commas instead of numbers in output JSON

Answer (score 0):

so in your current definition there is the issue with:

```
idJson=json.dumps(list(ServiceSubCategory.objects.values_list('id',flat=True)))
```

which returns an array, but you want this to be your new dict as I understand it, so replace this with

```
idJson={i:[] for i in list(ServiceSubCategory.objects.values_list('id',flat=True))}
```

allthough to be fair implementing greenwolf's suggestion looks better for the elegance of the program

EDIT**
your final result should look something like this:

```
def service(request):
    idList = list(ServiceSubCategory.objects.values_list('id',flat=True))
    idJson = {i:[] for i in idList}
    for i in idJson:
        cat = ServiceSubCategory.objects.get(id=i)
        dictionary=[obj.as_json() for obj in Service.objects.filter(service_sub_category=cat)]
        idJson[i].append(dictionary)
    return HttpResponse(idJson, content_type='application/json')
```

in your example, your array has a key:value pair and then another dict without a key. this is not allowed. arrays can have any objects but only integers as keys. dicts can have any hashable object as key and any other type as value, for a key:value pair. so your options are either use array where index number directly relates to item id:

```
[dict1,dict2,dict3, etc..]
```

where dict(id) looks like one of your dicts:

```
{"caption_fa": "some value", "caption_en": "something", "id": 2, "img_fa": "img/default_service.png"}
```

it can even be a list of dicts:

```
[[dict1,dict3],[dict2,dict4]]
```

or you can use dicts as was suggested:

```
{'1': [dict1,dict2], '2': [dict3,dict4]}
```

Comment: this returns `{"1": [], "2": [], "3": [], "4": [], "5": [], "6": [], "7": [], "8": [], "9": [], "10": []}`